# How do I invoke iOS photo editing extension?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-app-extension

Let's say I'm writing a word-processing application. Users can embed images using the app. Now since the application is *not* a photo editor, naturally it would delegate photo editing of embedded images to other applications.

The question is, how to do that? How to invoke [photo editing extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Photos.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH17-SW1) in an iOS app?

Theoretically it should be as simple as passing an image, invoke the extension, and then get another image back as the "edited" image. However the SDK documentation doesn't seem to provide any hint on how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the SDK doc actually says it doesn't provide a UI per se:

> When using built-in editing controls, the image picker controller enforces certain options. For still images, the picker enforces a square cropping as well as a maximum pixel dimension. For movies, the picker enforces a maximum movie length and resolution. If you want to let the user edit full-size media, or specify custom cropping, you must provide your own editing UI."

From:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html

I'm looking at the Adobe Creative SDK Image Editor, which seems to provide a UI. Might show some of their branding in the photo editor, however. Hope to follow up...